# Expandable RecyclerView Android Studio example

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I'm trying to find a good example Android Studio project for expandable recyclerview with the thoughtbot library, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is a complete tutorial for this: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/expandable-recyclerview-android/

Answer (score 0):

Use this library

```
'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
```

Check out complete usage of this [Expandable Layout](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout)